Hcpl 3120 peak voltage command
I’m using hcpl-3120 to command a Mosfet for a buck converter but the output command have a peak voltage, how can i reduce it, i used a snubber circuit between the gate and the source of the mosfet but without [
jpg

My guess the scope is lying to you. It is hard to measure the actual signal as the source is jumping up and down and this I would suggest is what you are seeing.

Yassine Derouech - Hi, You deleted your previous (currently closed) version of this question. The site lets you delete it, but then the expectation is you don't want to ask the question any more. Doing a "delete & repost" is bypassing one of the quality control mechanisms of the site, so it's not allowed. Therefore this question has been closed and will not be reopened.

(continued) If you want to continue with the topic, you can undelete the previous question and continue there. Also, it's unclear what you mean by "output command". Although you added a schematic, it was incomplete and did not show where you connected the scope. On the previous question, it will help people to understand your question if you add a photo of the real hardware, showing where the scope is connected.
